# Como mostrar todo o conteúdo de uma variável utilizando var_dump?

Tags: php, var-dump

Estou *debugando* um objeto (vamos assim dizer), mas, quando utilizo `var_dump`, não aparece todo o conteúdo desse objeto.

```
var_dump($obj[0]->link);
```

Resultado:

```
string '...atebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D236.263%26lmt%3D1575166829736796%26c%3DWEB%22'... (length=751)
```

Existe alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para conseguir visualizar o resto dessa string?

Comment: Tenta [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-export.php) ou [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php), veja alguma dessas funções são adequadas para o que precisa.

Comment: @AugustoVasques A resposta abaixo me ajudou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Existe alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para conseguir visualizar o resto dessa string?

Sim, existe.

Você pode configurar isso no seu `php.ini` adicionando/alterando essa linha:

`xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1`

Ou adicione isto ao topo do seu código `PHP`:

```
<?php

ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);
```

Aqui está uma resposta no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342948/11611028) em inglês.

Comment: Ótimo, a segunda opção funcionou.

Comment: Se funcionou, marque a resposta.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda, está pedindo para esperar 5 minutos.